# Jquery - response text as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this following jquery code to insert the responsetext in the div.

```
$("#div").load('page.php?val='+myvalue)
```

Is it possible to get the responsetext into a javascript variable instead of applying it to a div.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to replace `.load()` with `.get()` for instance.

```
$.get('page.php?val='+myvalue, function( data ) {
    console.log( data ); 
    // you might want to "store" the result in another variable here
});
```

One word of caution: the `data` parameter in the above snippet does not necesarilly shim the `responseText` property from the underlaying XHR object, but it'll contain whatever the request returned. If you need direct access to that, you can call it like

```
$.get('page.php?val='+myvalue, function( data, status, jXHR ) {
    console.log( jXHR.responseText ); 
});
```

Comment: Can i do something like this alert(console.log( jXHR.responseText ));

Comment: how do i get the value as a string?

Comment: @ravz: yes, `jXHR.responseText` should contain the response as string.

Answer (score 2):

Define a callback function like:

```
$("#div").load('page.php?val='+myvalue, function(responseText) {
    myVar = responseText;
});
```

Noticed everyone else is saying use `$.get` - you dont need todo this, it will work fine as above.

`.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )`

See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: when i alert(responseText) the whole doc's source was displayed.. how do i get the response text in a string?

Comment: docs source? What do you mean by that? If that url returns HTML code then thats what is being alerted. If you would like to treat it like a jQuery object then do `myVar = $(responseText);`

Comment: thanks dude. it worked.. but the get method suited me as i did not want to bring in #div into play..

Comment: @nav: it pretty much depends on the OPs needs. Your solution will still replace the contents from that element. To me the question sounds like how to avoid that and just grab the reponse.

Comment: ahh yes, didnt see the 'instead of' part :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use $.get method:

```
var variable = null;

$.get('page.php?val='+myvalue,function(response){
 variable = response;
});
```

More on this command: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

There's also a $.post and $.ajax commands

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    var request = $.ajax({
          url: "/ajax-url/",
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "html"
        });
    request.done(function(msg) {
        // here, msg will contain your response.
    });
```